# unicorn nginx upstream server not starting

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, unicorn

My unicorn server was running fine, but has stopped working and I can't figure out how to get it restarted.

```
2011/04/18 15:23:42 [error] 11907#0: *4 connect() to unix:/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 71.131.237.122, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock:/", host: "tacitus"
```

my config files are at: https://gist.github.com/926006

any help as to what my troubleshooting options should be would be greatly appreciated.

best,

Tim

Comment: I've got the same issue, do you maybe find the reason of this error?

Comment: this ServerFault question seems to cover the same topic:

http://serverfault.com/questions/398972/need-to-increase-nginx-throughput-to-an-upstream-unix-socket-linux-kernel-tun

Comment: Please look at this tutorial http://haidrali.com/lets-debug-nginx-unicorn-errors/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had similar issue with nginx and unicorn setup.

Every day I've seen in nginx error.log this error:

```
failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream
```

The way I fixed it was to change unix socket to tcp socket.

so instead

```
upstream unicorn_app {
  server unix:/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
```

now I'm using

```
upstream unicorn_app {
  server 127.0.0.1:3000 fail_timeout=0;
}
```

Hope it will help someone.

Comment: Where you have "unicorn_app", is that just the name of the app itself? Or do you mean literally put "unicorn_app" there?

Comment: which file is it?